# VueJS Vuex Action explanation

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm a beginner in vueJS and  I'd like to know something about actions. As far as I know, I've seen that they would handle asynchronous code while mutations hold synchronous one.
I'd like to understand something . Let's suppose I call an API when a component / view gets mounted :

```
mounted(){
          fetch("http://localhost:100/api/v1/tags")
          .then(response =>
            response.json())
          .then(
           data => { 
            this.dbTags = [...data.map(item => item.nom)]
            this.$store.commit('changeTagsApiValueToTrue');
            }
          )
```

I used commit here and it works but I want to know whether it is correct to use it when the code outside of the action is asynchronous. What I mean is, does the code inside the action part of the vuex file should be asynchronous or every single asynchronous functionality that is using vuex (such as fetching an api from a component / view ) should have its data handled by actions.

Comment: Mutations are supposed to be low-level and generally used by actions, but this is not strict, they are expected to be removed in next Vuex version any way. The concerns with low and high level ops are still valid though. Is there a reason why this asynchronous piece of code is not an action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with calling a synchronous method from an asynchronous chain.

You only need to use actions (aka dispatch) when your **call into the store** uses asynchronous code.

In other words, if your call to `commit` called `fetch`, you should use `dispatch` instead.

```
store.dispatch('doFetch', 'http://localhost:100/api/v1/tags')
```

Then your 'doFetch' action would call `fetch`, and eventually call `commit`

If your address was always the same, it would simply be:

```
store.dispatch('doFetch')
```

Comment: so if the code inside of the action method uses asynchronous data, it would be necessary. But in the case I've show in my post it is not needed

Comment: Correct.  But it also might make more sense to put your async code in an action, and call `commit` from the action.  So your 'dispatch' would do the fetch, then call `commit`.